# Are there any video players with commercial skip for Android?

Tags: video, media-player

I have a TiVo Series 3 and the [TiVo Desktop Plus](https://www3.tivo.com/store/accessories-desktoppluspc.do) software, which I use to convert shows for playback on my iPod Touch.  I'd love to find a video player that would have 30 second/commercial skip for an Android phone (future purchase).  It's hard for me to adjust the slider on the video player with that degree of precision.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an actual 30 second button, but [MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad) has a feature to slowly adjust forward and backward (a full screen swipe typically does ~45-60 seconds), making it very easy to precisely navigate a video.